# Sending email via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send an email from my project, but I'm having some trouble...

I'm using this code:

```
private void SendMail()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(MailSender, MailReciever, MailSubject, MailContent);
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SMTPServer);

    client.Send(mail);
}
```

Then I get an exception :

> *The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not
>   authenticated*

I don't know what to do. Any suggestions ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Instead of stating `I don't know what to do` perhaps you could have looked at the `Related` section on this page as well as do a Stackoverflow search for the topic since there are tons of answers as well as working examples.. lack of effort I must say `Etrit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the network credential to authenticate the request

```
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword");
```

Comment: Extremely over answered topic...

Comment: May also need to [EnableSsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx) (depending on the smtp server).

Comment: That does not make it available for Downvote ...

Comment: @Etrit:- Please accept this as an answer then ...

Comment: Done. Just needed to wait the countdown to accept an answer :)